# Cannot see browser when running Selenium tests in Hudson

Tags: browser, selenium, hudson, automated-tests

As said in the title, I'm running Selenium tests in Hudson, using the SeleniumHQ plugin, on windows 7.

I'm running the tests as part of a Hudson job, which is executed by a slave.  The slave is installed as a windows service, and its identity is set to Local system account, WITH the right to interact with the desktop.

My problem is that I cannot see the browser while the tests are running (but they do run and pass)

Can anyone help ?

Thanks
 David

Comment: Are you using WebDriver? My idea is that if yes, using HTMLUnitDriver will not show the browser.

Comment: Yes, I'm using webdrivers, with Selenese html.However, if I run manually the same command in Windows command line, the browser shows normally.

Comment: The problem is running the Hudson slave as a service. When you start it within a RDP session you will see the browser.

Comment: How can I test that locally? I'm running everything on my local machine.
Edit: Ok, it works after running the agent using JNLP